# Postgres Upgrade Issues with pg_upgrade

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-12

I am trying to upgrade 9.5.5 to 12.3 using pg_uprade, got the following error

*Old and new pg_controldata maximum relation segment sizes are invalid or do not match*

**9.5.5**

Blocks per segment of large relation: 8388608

**12.3**

Blocks per segment of large relation: 131072

8388608 blocks is equivalent to 64 GB.

I recompiled the 12.3 version using the following options

*./configure --prefix=/opt/pgsql/PostgreSQL-12 --with-segsize=64*

pg_controldata output 9.5.5

```
pg_control version number:            942
Catalog version number:               201510051
Database system identifier:           6307574991682851055
Database cluster state:               shut down
pg_control last modified:             Thu 01 Oct 2020 07:15:50 PM EDT
Latest checkpoint location:           2FB/7C000028
Prior checkpoint location:            2FB/78000098
Latest checkpoint's REDO location:    2FB/7C000028
Latest checkpoint's REDO WAL file:    00000001000002FB0000001F
Latest checkpoint's TimeLineID:       1
Latest checkpoint's PrevTimeLineID:   1
Latest checkpoint's full_page_writes: on
Latest checkpoint's NextXID:          0/130082037
Latest checkpoint's NextOID:          182620
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiXactId:  1
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiOffset:  0
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID:        1741
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID's DB:   1
Latest checkpoint's oldestActiveXID:  0
Latest checkpoint's oldestMultiXid:   1
Latest checkpoint's oldestMulti's DB: 1
Latest checkpoint's oldestCommitTsXid:0
Latest checkpoint's newestCommitTsXid:0
Time of latest checkpoint:            Thu 01 Oct 2020 07:15:50 PM EDT
Fake LSN counter for unlogged rels:   0/1
Minimum recovery ending location:     0/0
Min recovery ending loc's timeline:   0
Backup start location:                0/0
Backup end location:                  0/0
End-of-backup record required:        no
wal_level setting:                    hot_standby
wal_log_hints setting:                off
max_connections setting:              1000
max_worker_processes setting:         8
max_prepared_xacts setting:           0
max_locks_per_xact setting:           64
track_commit_timestamp setting:       off
Maximum data alignment:               8
Database block size:                  8192
Blocks per segment of large relation: 8388608
WAL block size:                       8192
Bytes per WAL segment:                67108864
Maximum length of identifiers:        64
Maximum columns in an index:          32
Maximum size of a TOAST chunk:        1996
Size of a large-object chunk:         2048
Date/time type storage:               64-bit integers
Float4 argument passing:              by value
Float8 argument passing:              by value
Data page checksum version:           0
```

pg_controldata output 12.3

```
pg_control version number:            942
Catalog version number:               201510051
Database system identifier:           6307574991682851055
Database cluster state:               shut down
pg_control last modified:             Thu 01 Oct 2020 07:15:50 PM EDT
Latest checkpoint location:           2FB/7C000028
Prior checkpoint location:            2FB/78000098
Latest checkpoint's REDO location:    2FB/7C000028
Latest checkpoint's REDO WAL file:    00000001000002FB0000001F
Latest checkpoint's TimeLineID:       1
Latest checkpoint's PrevTimeLineID:   1
Latest checkpoint's full_page_writes: on
Latest checkpoint's NextXID:          0/130082037
Latest checkpoint's NextOID:          182620
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiXactId:  1
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiOffset:  0
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID:        1741
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID's DB:   1
Latest checkpoint's oldestActiveXID:  0
Latest checkpoint's oldestMultiXid:   1
Latest checkpoint's oldestMulti's DB: 1
Latest checkpoint's oldestCommitTsXid:0
Latest checkpoint's newestCommitTsXid:0
Time of latest checkpoint:            Thu 01 Oct 2020 07:15:50 PM EDT
Fake LSN counter for unlogged rels:   0/1
Minimum recovery ending location:     0/0
Min recovery ending loc's timeline:   0
Backup start location:                0/0
Backup end location:                  0/0
End-of-backup record required:        no
wal_level setting:                    hot_standby
wal_log_hints setting:                off
max_connections setting:              1000
max_worker_processes setting:         8
max_prepared_xacts setting:           0
max_locks_per_xact setting:           64
track_commit_timestamp setting:       off
Maximum data alignment:               8
Database block size:                  8192
Blocks per segment of large relation: 8388608
WAL block size:                       8192
Bytes per WAL segment:                67108864
Maximum length of identifiers:        64
Maximum columns in an index:          32
Maximum size of a TOAST chunk:        1996
Size of a large-object chunk:         2048
Date/time type storage:               64-bit integers
Float4 argument passing:              by value
Float8 argument passing:              by value
Data page checksum version:           0
```

And ran pg_upgrade again, and get the same error as above.
What am I missing here?

Comment: The docs say that --segsize is specified in GB, not in blocks.  When I configure and build with `--with-segsize=8388608`, I get a nonfunctional build.

Comment: I figured that, basically it's equivalent to 64 GB and re-ran, but get the same error.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - Edited the original question and pasted the output for both clusters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after numerous tests, I found the issue.
If I run the configure --with-segsize=64 on RHEL 6.10, the segment size will not get set to 64 GB, but if I run it on RHEL 7.8, it does.
Seems like a bug with RHEL 6.10.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have posted the `pg_controldata` output for PostgreSQL 9.5 twice.

Anyway, you'll have to configure PostgreSQL v12 with a non-standard table segment size:

```bash
./configure --prefix=/opt/pgsql/PostgreSQL-12 --with-segsize=64
```

Also, during `initdb`, you will have to specify the non-standard WAL segment size:

```bash
initdb ... --wal-segsize=64 /path/to/datadir
```

Then `pg_upgrade` should succeed (if locale etc. match).

Comment: I double-checked, re-ran the configure and initdb with the options suggested, it still throws the same error

Comment: Are you using `pg_upgrade` from v12? Does `pg_cuntroldata -D <datadir>` show the same segment size for both?

Comment: Despite of running this                                                       ./configure --prefix=/opt/pgsql/PostgreSQL-12 --with-segsize=64,                            the segment size never changes. This is what I get                                                                
Blocks per segment of large relation: 131072.

Comment: Then the problem must be that you are inadvertedly using a PostgreSQL installation different from the one you configured. Check your `PATH` setting or use absolute paths. Use the `-D` option of `pg_controldata`.

Comment: So after numerous tests, I found the issue. If I run the configure --with-segsize=64 on RHEL 6.10, the segment size will not get set to 64 GB, but if I run it on RHEL 7.8, it does. Seems like a bug.